# Should I keep a unix local socket open, or keep opening and closing it?

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, local, freebsd

I am writing the client and server side for multi-threaded applications. For a local socket IPC (AF_LOCAL), should I keep the socket open all the time on the client side, or should I keep opening and closing it?

My server side binds to the socket and waits for connections, it might send a confirmation response to client in some cases.

The client might be sending messages to server intermittently, so should we be opening and closing the socket every time I am sending a message, or should I keep the socket open on client side, through the life of the application.

Comment: As they say: it depends... How often do you read and write on the socket compared to the idling time? You need to share more details.

Comment: Does having a persistent connection to the server cause resource starvation?

Comment: as @LaszloPapp suggests, it depends - are you talking about a dozen open/close cycles over the course of 5 minutes, or a thousand open/close cycles in just a couple seconds? The first case could reasonably be handled by repeated open/close cycles to avoid holding on to resources unnecessarily. The second is a prime candidate for a persistent connection, and will probably even be noticably faster if you keep the connection open...

Comment: Thanks for responses. My application might have thousands going on in seconds in some cases or one/two every hour or so. I am going to check if there is something on the queue and if there is, I will keep socket open, otherwise, I will close it, and open next time we got something to send.